# opposite action to Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.clear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

This is a very straight and simple question:

Is there any way to *populate* o *re create* the ScheduledSet jobs? I mean something opposite to **Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.clear** ?

Or, can I run `average_scheduled_poll_interval` from the rails console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I found something similar to what I was looking for: basically, what I wanted is that the workers to reload the changes in the source code, and found this [answer](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-get-sidekiq-workers-to-reload-automatically-when-i-change-the-source-code) in the FAQ page.

It needs an extra [gem](https://github.com/alexch/rerun), but it does the job.